# Why does `then` even exist and when should it be used?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

If one of the goals with Promises is to prevent callback hell, why does `then` even exist and when should it be used?

Example:

```
//If this
someFunction.then((retunValue) => {

});

//Can be written like so:
const returnValue = await someFunction();
```

Why would anyone choose to write it the first way?

When should `then` be used today?

Comment: Because `await` is a new feature that not every browser implements.  There are also cases where you don't want to block or suspend execution in this way.

Comment: @B001ᛦ becuase multiple .then in side of other .then can look sloppy and is pretty much the same as callback hell

Comment: And, `await` actually uses `.then()` in order to do its job in some cases.

Comment: Top-level `await` doesn't even exist yet.

Comment: Callback hell means callback within callback ... (a lot of nested callbacks). `then` prevents that by chaining the callbacks in a cleaner way (**chaining** is a lot cleaner than **nesting**)

Comment: if async, we prefer async all the way. some projects may has only some modules uses async, it may prefer to use `.then()` instead.

Comment: @orangeMint You might want to have a look at [how promise `then` improves on callback hell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562045/1048572) by having a return value

Comment: @jfriend00 `await` uses `then` to do its job in *all* cases

Comment: "*…and when should it be used?*" - there are still [some cases in exception handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await) where `then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` is superior to `await`+`try`/`catch`.

Comment: @Bergi - Are you sure there are no internally optimized code paths with native promises that bypass actually calling a `.then()` method, particularly when the only listener is one `await`?

Comment: The most obvious reason to use it today is when you are targeting a platform that does not support `async/await`, like IE 11 for instance. You could transpile code for those platforms using transpilers like Babel though.

Comment: @jfriend00 No, I'm not sure about that, but I think that would digress into a discussion about when an optimisation (such as inlining) is still considered a method call and when not :-)

Comment: @Bergi - Well that's why I didn't say it always uses `.then()`.  I thought I may have a short cut path with native promises.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`then` predates `async`/`await` by some years.

Even with `then` you avoid callback hell because you can *chain* it (and use interstitial variables as part of the chaining) instead of *nesting* callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

[await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/operators/await) pause execution of current function until promise is resolved/rejected, while [then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/promise/then) creates new promise and execution of the current function continues.

Consider following code that has different results for await -vs- then:

```js
const wait = (num) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(resolve, num);
});

async function main() {
  await wait(1000);
  console.log('await: first');
  await wait(50);
  console.log('await: second');

// - VS -

  wait(1000).then(() => console.log('then: first'));
  wait(50).then(() => console.log('then: second'));
}

main();
```

Comment: Well this has different results only because you translated from `await` to `then` incorrectly. It needs to be `return wait(1000).then(() => { console.log('then: first'); return wait(50).then(() => { console.log('then: second'); }); });`

Answer (score 0):

The super short answer is that `.then()` came first and there was no reason to remove it from the language when `await` came along later.  In fact, even now that we have `await`, there are still reasons when `.then()` and/or `.catch()` are more convenient or more suited for the task than `await`.  Here are some of those reasons:

1. It predates `await` and was the only way to get values out of a promise for several years.
2. There are situations where `p.then(fnResolve, fnReject)` is useful.
3. There are situations where a single `p.catch()` or `p.then().catch()` is easier and simpler than using `await` with `try/catch` around it.
4. There are situations where you don't want the entire function to be suspended like `await` will do, but you still want a handler for when the promise is done.
5. We do not yet have top level `await` in many environments yet so with top level promises, the only way to get the value out at the top level is to use `.then()` or wrap it in a non-top level function.
6. Higher level promise control flow functions such as `Promise.all()`, `Promise.race()` and `Promise.allSettled()` and the many others that people have designed themselves all use `.then()` to monitor multiple promise chains that are in-flight at once because they don't want to force sequencing which is what `await` is designed for.  In other words, `await` is designed to help you sequence things one after another.  It lets you create a promise chain and "waits" for it to finish before executing the next line of code.  Sometimes, that is not the desired control flow.  Sometimes you want things in flight at the same time, not sequenced.

So, while `await` can replace `.then()` in many cases, they are not identical and there are still situations where `.then()` is useful instead of `await` and, of course, it existed first so it isn't about to be removed from the language.

**Discussion of item #1:**

Before `await`, the only way to get a value out of a promise was with `.then()` and there was no need to remove `.then()` when `await` was later added.

```
someAsynchronousFunc().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
}).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I even used regular functions because promises predated arrow functions too.

**Discussion of item #2:**

As Bergi shows [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await), there are times when it's easier to isolate one specific error source with the structure:

```
p.then(fnResolve, fnReject)
```

You can, certainly achieve the same result with `await`, but not as cleanly.  I won't repeat the above referenced answer here.  Please read it for details.

**Discussion of item #3:**

There are situations where a single `p.catch()` or `p.then().catch()` is easier and simpler than using `await` with `try/catch` around it.

I regular see this when I have a bunch of logic involving asynchronous operations and then there's some final cleanup at the end like closing files.  I don't need to `await` that as the rest of the flow doesn't need to wait for it, I don't intend to propagate a close error, I do need to catch errors and I do need to log the error.  So, I choose to do something like this:

```
async function someFunc() {
     let fileHandle;
     try {
         ... multiple pieces of business logic using await
     } catch(e) {
         ... handle errors in business logic
     } finally {
         if (fileHandle) {
             fileHandle.close().catch(err => {
                 console.log("Error closing file", err);
             });
         }
     }
}
```

I choose not to use `await` primarily because I don't need `someFunc()` to wait for the `close()` operation to complete and I'm not trying to propagate any error with `close()`, particularly if all I was doing was reading from the file.  A close error is both highly unlikely (when only reading) and also of no real consequence. This could be done with `await`, but it would both be more code and would wait when I don't want it to wait.  The single `.catch()` is just simpler.

**Discussion of item #4:**

There are situations where you don't want the entire function to be suspended like `await` will do, but you still want a handler for when the promise is done.

This would mostly occur when you're branching your promise chain into a separate, independent promise chain. This isn't that common a pattern, but does occasionally happen.  Let's suppose that you have some middleware that collects statistics in a separate database server.  You'd like to know if there are errors in recording the statistics, but it's not something you want to communicate back to the user and it's not something you want the response back to the http request to "wait" for.  In this case, you want to fire off a new separate promise chain to record the statistics that you main promise chain does not wait for.

```
app.use("/update", (req, res, next) => {
    // update statistics in separate database
    updateStats(req).catch(err => {
        // log error
        console.log("updateStats error", req.url, err);
    });
    // continue on the request chain without waiting for stats update to finish
    next();
});
```

**Discussion of item #5:**

We do not yet have top level await in many environments yet so with top level promises, the only way to get the value out at the top level is to use `.then()` or wrap it in a non-top level function.

If you have a promise at the top level, then you can do this:

```
someAsyncFunc(...).then(result => {
    // do something with result
}).catch(err => {
    // do something with error
});
```

Or, you can do something like this:

```
(async function() {
    try {
        let result = await someAsyncFunc(...);
        // do something with result
    } catch(e) {
        // do something with error
    }
})();
```

There are times when the 2nd form may actually be the desirable solution, particularly if you're trying to sequence multiple asynchronous operations, all with `await`.  But, if the solution is no more complex than what we have above, the `async` IIFE is clearly a contrived structure just to allow the user a single `await`.  It's not simpler or cleaner.

**Discussion of item #6:**

Higher level promise control flow functions such as `Promise.all()`, `Promise.race()` and `Promise.allSettled()` and the many others that people have designed themselves (such as `mapConcurrent()` that I mentioned below) all use `.then()` and/or `.catch()` to monitor multiple promise chains that are in-flight at once.

If you're going to have multiple asynchronous operations in flight at once, you (somewhat by definition), do not want to `await` each individual one.  Instead, you want to launch them all, use some code that monitors them all and then provide some summary information when a specific condition has been met.  With `Promise.all()`, you want to know when the first one rejects or when all have succeeded.  With `Promise.race()`, you want to know when the first one rejects or succeeds.  With `Promise.allSettled()`, you want to know when they are all done (whether successfully or not).  None of these are implemented with `await` because all the asynchronous operations are launched in parallel.  `await` is designed to serialize asynchronous operations.  It doesn't do parallel operation.

For example, if you want to fetch an array of URLs, you might do this:

```
Promise.all([url1, url2, url3].map(url => {
   return got(url);
})).then(arrayOfData => {
    console.log(arrayOfData);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This particular code could use `await`, like this:

```
try {
    let arrayOfData = await Promise.all([url1, url2, url3].map(url => {
        return got(url);
    });
    console.log(arrayOfData);
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
}
```

But, internal to the implementation of `Promise.all()` or any other function that is managing N promises in flight at the same time, it doesn't want to use `await` because it doesn't want to serialize the operations, it wants to allow them to run in parallel and monitor them in parallel with `.then()` and `.catch()` (not serialize them with `await`).

Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654265/promise-all-consumes-all-my-ram/46654592#46654592) of a function named `mapConcurrent()` that lets you process an array of items, calling some asynchronous function on each item in the array, but rather than running the entire array in parallel, it runs N operations at a time in parallel (to conserve memory usage and in some cases to keep from overwhelming the target server or avoid rate limiting).  That implementation, like others that do something similar to manage parallel asynchronous operations using promises, all use `.then()` and `.catch()` to monitor multiple operations in flight at the same time.

Comment: I think points 2 and 3 need elaboration, and 4 is a moot point, because you don't need to immediately await a Promise.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Ìt's about `const p = doSomething().then(r => handle(r));` vs `const p = (async () { const r = await doSomething(); return handle(r); })();`

Comment: @Bergi I'm not sure what point your trying to make? Just that `then` is more concise within a sync context? What if `p` also needs to be awaited?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Yes, that's point 4. It might not be a particularly strong one, but it's still a valid reason to use `then`. And the assumption is that `p` is not being `await`ed, but e.g. passed to `Promise.all`.

Comment: @Bergi Ok fair enough, I'm not sure that is what point 4 is about, but it is a benefit. The `async` version could be simplified as well: `const p = (async () => handle(await doSomething()))();`, although still more verbose than `then`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - For point 4, sometimes you may have multiple promise sequences within a function and you want them to proceed in parallel so you aren't trying to await one before executing the next. You may or may not be using `Promise.all()` to track when they are all done.  Oh, I guess I could add a sixth point because things like `Promise.all()` and `Promise.race()` and `Promise.allSettled()` all use `.then()` to track multiple promise chains that are all in-flight at the same time and it would be a lot more difficult for them to do what they do by using only `await`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - If folks are interested, I can offer code examples of these points.  The question already has an accepted answer (though a bit simplistic one) - I wasn't sure if people were interested or not.  I won't be back online until much later today to work on this.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think it would be useful. Comments such as _There are situations where `p.then(fnResolve, fnReject)` is useful._ don't really mean much without an example.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay - I added code examples and more detailed explanation for each point.