# Why isnt the final console.log showing the whole data even after waiting for all promises to resolve?

Tags: javascript, node.js

#### Edit

So if I set a `setTimeout` on my final `console.log`, it will log fine, but I guess my new question is although, even with the `then` statements, why isnt the it triggering after everything is resolved?

I am having an odd bug that I cant figure out why it is not printing the whole structure that I am expecting. I am not getting any errors, and I did try putting in a few `console.log`, but just get seem to get the `anyOf` property to log. It always shows empty.

My main issue is that `hold` is not logging correctly. It is showing `anyOf` as empty.

```js
const $ = require('cheerio');
const Axios = require('axios').default;
let name = 'sqs';
let basePath = '/AWS_SQS.html'


let hold = {
    '$schema': 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#',
    '$id': `cf${name}`,
    'description': `CF ${name}`,
    'properties': {
        'Type': {
            'type': 'string',
            'enum': [],
        },
    },
    'anyOf': [] // this keeps coming up empty
};

let typeProperties = (t, p) => {
    return {
        'if': { 'properties': { 'Type': { 'const': t } } },
        'then': {
            'properties': {
                'Properties': {
                    'type': 'object',
                    'properties': p,
                },
            },
        },
    }
}

const makeRequest = (bpath) => {
    let url = 'https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/' + bpath
    return Axios.get(url)
        .then((res) => {
            return res.data;
        })
        .catch(console.log);
};

let getData = makeRequest(basePath).then((data) => {
    let match = $('.listitem>p>a', data);
    match.map((i, e) => {
        let t = $(e);
        hold.properties.Type.enum.push(t.text());
        makeRequest(t.attr('href')).then((newdata) => {
            let holdProperties = {}
            let pType = $($('.variablelist', newdata)[0])
            $('.term>.code', pType).map((i, elem) => {
                let propertyName = $(elem).text()
                holdProperties[propertyName] = {}
            })
            hold.anyOf.push(typeProperties(t.text(), holdProperties))
        }).catch(console.log)
    });
}).catch(console.log)

getData.then(() => {
    // Why doesnt this log fully once everything is resolved? If i put a setTimeout here, it will work fine
    console.log(JSON.stringify(hold));
}).catch(console.log)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of the code associated with `getData()`, you are doing `makeRequest().then()` inside a `.map()`, but completely ignoring the promises that `makeRequest()` is returning.  You're not waiting for them.  You need to use `Promise.all()` to wait on all of them so you can return a promise that is linked to all those other promises finishing.

You can do so like this:

```
let getData = makeRequest(basePath).then((data) => {
    let match = $('.listitem>p>a', data).get();
    return Promise.all(match.map(item => {
        let t = $(item);
        hold.properties.Type.enum.push(t.text());
        return makeRequest(t.attr('href')).then((newdata) => {
            let holdProperties = {}
            let pType = $($('.variablelist', newdata)[0])
            $('.term>.code', pType).map((i, elem) => {
                let propertyName = $(elem).text()
                holdProperties[propertyName] = {}
            })
            hold.anyOf.push(typeProperties(t.text(), holdProperties))
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
            throw err;              // propagate error back to caller
        });
    }));
}).catch(console.log)

getData.then(() => {
    // Why doesnt this log fully once everything is resolved? If i put a setTimeout here, it will work fine
    console.log(JSON.stringify(hold));
}).catch(console.log)
```

Changes in this code:

1. Inside the `.map()` add `return` so you have `return makeRequest(...)` so your `.map()` will return an array of promises.
2. With that array of promises from `.map()` use `return Promise.all(match.map(...))` so you're waiting for all the promises from the `.map()` and so you're returning that summary promise.
3. Get a real array from jQuery/cheerio using `.get()` so you can use real ES6 iteration operations with it.
4. Then switch the arguments to `.map()` to match what an `array.map()` uses.

Note, your `hold.anyOf` array will have results in no guaranteed order since all your parallel `makeRequest()` calls could finish in any order.  If you want them in order, you should return the value from the `.then()` handler and then `Promise.all()` will accumulate all the values in order and you can then use them from the array that is the resolved value of `Promise.all()` where they will be in the order you requested them.

Comment: Thanks for the catch. But do you know why I am getting a `TypeError: [object Object] is not iterable` in the `Promises.all`?

Comment: @securisec - Yeah, this is the crappy jQuery or cheerio objects whatever it is you're using.  They don't support modern ES6 iteration and aren't real arrays.  I can offer you a fix in moment.

Comment: Yes, I really agree with you. I faced the issue initially when I was just trying to get some arrays back, but thank you. That really was a great catch. I will wait for the fix.

Comment: @securisec - OK, I made a change in the code in my answer to get a real array here `let match = $('.listitem>p>a', data).get();`, then use `match.map()` to be a real array that we're doing `.map()` on and then change the arguments to the `.map()` callback to match what `array.map()` does.  I can't test it myself so it's possible it needs some more tweaking.

Comment: @securisec - FYI, I had the exact same issue in another answer (only 10 mins ago) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62685802/how-can-i-handle-a-file-of-30000-urls-without-memory-leaks/62686466?noredirect=1#comment110890239_62686466).  jQuery/cheerio are hard to use modern ES6 iteration with which is needed a lot more often now with asynchronous calls and `async/await`.  Different problem in that other answer, but same obstacle with the antiquated jQuery/cheerio API getting in the way.  Anyway, the solution is the same.  Get a real array and then use real array iteration.

Comment: Thank you for the fantastic explanation!