# interject synchronous code into asynchoronous

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, asynchronous, lighthouse

I'm running the [lighthouse cli](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) against a ~50 site list of sites. I'm simply running it in a `.forEach` loop, which, if I understand, is blocking, aka, synchronous. However, I end up spinning up 50 Chrome Canary instances all at once. In my limited understanding of these things I think the thread is started synchronously, but then `node` can pass the thread off to the kernel and happily start the next. Again, that's just my hand-wavy understanding of what's going on.

I'm using this function that I cribbed from somewhere:

```
function launchChromeAndLighthouse(url, opts, config = null) {
  return chromeLauncher.launch({chromeFlags: opts.chromeFlags}).then(chrome => {
    opts.port = chrome.port;
    return lighthouse(url, opts, config).then(results =>
      chrome.kill().then(() => results));
  });
}
```

I tried `nextTick` in the loop:

```
asyncFuncs().then( async (sites) => {
  sites.forEach( (site) => {
    process.nextTick(launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(site.url, opts))
  })
})
```

But this still spawns a bunch of Chrome instances. How do I pause execution while one lighthouse completes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `launchChromeAndRunLighthouse()` returns a promise to mark when it's done, if you want to only run them serially one at a time, you can switch to a `for` loop and use `await`:

```
asyncFuncs().then( async (sites) => {
  for (let site of sites) {
    await launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(site.url, opts);
  }
});
```

If you're trying to collect all the results:

```
asyncFuncs().then( async (sites) => {
    let results = [];
    for (let site of sites) {
      let r = await launchChromeAndRunLighthouse(site.url, opts);
      results.push(r);
    }
    return results;
}).then(results => {
    // all results here
}).catch(err => {
    // process error here
});
```

---

If you want to run N chrome instances at a time such that it initially starts up N instances and then each time one finishes, you launch the next one that's waiting, that is more complicated to keep track of how many instances are running.  There's a helper function call `pMap()` or `mapConcurrent()` that can do that for you in these answers:

[Make several requests to an API that can only handle 20 request a minute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378923/make-several-requests-to-an-api-that-can-only-handle-20-request-a-minute/33379149#33379149)

[Promise.all consumes all my RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46654265/promise-all-consumes-all-my-ram/46654592#46654592)

---

The [Bluebird Promise library](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) also has concurrency control in its [`Promise.map()` function](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.map.html).